# socketio + sails: does not receive response in socket frame

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I created a socket server with sails. I use socket.io.js and sails.io.js to test, but the results are not the same
I couldn't find the reason why.
I want to fix socket.io to work the same as sails.io, for clients not using the sails framework

In my sample, 
I created ChatController in sails server

```
/**
 * ChatController
 */
module.exports = {
    subcriber: function (req, res) {
        return res.send('done');
    },
};
```

In client code, I try socket.io and sails.io in turn. Both were able to call the function (by see the log on the server), but the client using socket.io did not receive the response like sails.io

client use sails.io

```
io.socket.get('/chat/subcriber', function responseFromServer(body, response) {
    console.log("The server responded with status " + response.statusCode + " and said: ", body);
});
```

and client use socket.io

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var socket = io('http://localhost:1337/', {
            transports: ['websocket'],
            query: SDK_INFO.versionString
        });
socket.emit('get', { method: "get", headers: {}, data: {}, url: "/chat/subcriber" });
```

This is results

1. client use socket.io https://prnt.sc/n2ya3w
2. client use sails.io https://prnt.sc/n2y9yz

I would like for the client to use socket.io can also get a response like the client use sails.io
Can anyone give me experience on this issue?
Thanks